# Build Object step by step obligatorily

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i need to create objects following an sequence of rules

```
public class MyClass {
    private Double field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private Double fiels3;
    //getters setters
}
```

I need to calculate first field1:

```
MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.setField1(OtherClass.calculateField1(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3));
```

Than calculate field2, but field1 must be calculated before, because to calculate the second field2 need field1 to be done:

```
MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.setField1(OtherClass.getField2(object, parameter4, parameter5));
```

For set field3 i need the field2 and field1 calculated, and so on

How force who is creating the object MyClass to follow this sequence o creation?
A Chain of resposability can help me?

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/07/builder-pattern-with-a-twist/

Answer (score 1):

Few options, ordered from more from more appropiated to less

- Force calculation throught constructor
- Force calculation throught one single method
- Throw exception in setField2 if field1 is not set

Comment: Side note: The exception thrown in 3 should be probably be `IllegalStateException`.